# Link does not work because of event listener

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
const myContainer = document.querySelector("my-container");
const linkElement = document.querySelector("link-element");

function handleMouseDown(event) {
if (myContainer.contains(event.target)) {
    // do something
    }
}

HTML
<div class="my-container">
    <a href="/mylink" class="link-element"></a>
</div>
```

when clicked on "a" tag, the link does not work for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: QuerySelector must contain the complete css selector : `document.querySelector(".my-container")` `document.querySelector(".link-element");` (you didn t include the dot of the class selector)

Answer (score 0):

With a few changes you can make it work:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
const container = document.querySelector(".my-container *");
const linkElement = document.querySelector(".link-element");

function handleMouseDown(event) {
  if (container.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log(event.type+" in container!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <a href="/mylink" class="link-element">some link to click</a>
</div>
```

Some minor ssues were:

- your css selectors were missing a ".",
- your `a` element did not have an inner text - there was nothing to click on,
- `.contains()` *is a valid DOM element method* - yes, you can use it!

Comment: Hi, why not use contains ? Seems valid for this case isnt it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: Thanks @Peterrabbit - I was not aware of this!